# CPLEX outputting different results on consecutive runs - Asynchronity issue?

Tags: asynchronous, cplex

I'm running CPLEX from IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.6.
Here I'm facing a weird issue. Solving the same optimization problem (pure LP) multiple times in a row, yields different results.

The aim is to solve once, then iteratively modify the coefficient matrix, and re-solve the problem. However, we experienced that the changes between iterations did not correspond to the modifications.
This lead us to try re-solving the problem without doing modifications in between, which returned different results.

The catch is that we still do one major modification before we start iterating, and our hypothesis is that this change (`cplex.setCoef(...)` on about 10,000 rows) is done asynchronously, so that it is only partially done during the first re-solution iterations.

However, we cannot seem to find any documentation stating that this method is asynchronous, nor any way to ensure synchronous execution, so that all the changes are done before CPLEX restarts.

Does anyone know if this is the case? Is there any way to delay restart until `cplex.setCoef(...)` is done? The problem is quite huge, but the representative lines are:

```
functionUsingSetCoefOn10000rows();
for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    cplex.solve();
    writeln("Iteration " + j + ": " + cplex.getObjValue());
    for(var k = 0; k < 100000; k++){
        doBusyWork(); //Just to kill time               
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
Iteration 0: 1529486959.814946
Iteration 1: 1544325969.750444
Iteration 2: 1549669732.757587
Iteration 3: 1551818419.584333
...
Iteration 33: 1564007987.849925
...
Iteration 98: 1564007987.849925
Iteration 99: 1564007987.849925
```

**Last minute update**
Reducing the number of calls to `cplex.setCoef` to about 2500 removes the issue, and all iterations return the same objective value. Sadly, we do need to change all the 10,000 coefficients.

**Edit:** The OPL scripting and engine log: http://goo.gl/ywJhkm and here: http://goo.gl/v2Qhm9

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this is not really an answer, but it is too big to go as a comment...

I don't think that the setCoef() calls would be asynchronous and not complete - that would be very surprising. Such behaviour would be too unpredictable and too many other people would have problems with this behaviour. However, CPLEX itself will use multiple threads to solve a problem and that means that it can generate different solutions each time it runs. The example objective values that you show do seem to change significantly, so a few questions/observations:

1: The numbers seem to be monotonically increasing - are they all increasing like this until they reach the maximum value? It looks like some kind of convergence behaviour. On re-running, CPLEX will start from a previous solution if it can. Check that there isn't some other CPLEX parameter stopping the search early such as an iteration or time limit or wider solution optimality tolerance.

2: Have you looked at the CPLEX logs from each run to see what CPLEX is doing in each run?

3: If you have doubts about the model being solved, try dumping out the model as an LP file and check the values in each iteration. They should all be the same in your case. You can also try solving the LP file in the CPLEX standalone optimiser to see what value that gives.

4: Have you tried setting the parameters to make CPLEX use a different LP algorithm (e.g. primal simplex, barrier etc)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! We dumped the lp-file, and the same problem is solved in each iteration.

Comment: 1. They are all increasing until they reach the maximum value. There are no limits on iteration or time. There's an optimality tolerance (http://goo.gl/vUq4Ah), and changing this to its minimal value yields somewhat different results if we do not warm start the model by reading the optimal basis. The initial objective value is closer to the one that the iterations converge to, but the maximum value is lower than with the default tolerance. If the optimal basis is read, the results are identical with both tolerances. The question is updated with scripting and engine logs.